# second featured post not displaying on page

Tags: images, templates, post-thumbnails

hi so i added the multipostthumbnails plugin and got everything setup ok, but now when i try to display the thumbnail in my template the post image does not show up. i've checked the [docs](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) on multiposts and it turns out you can't use [get_post_type()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) when in your header or on a single page you have to pass the post type directly, but i still can't get the url to show up for my background image.
any thoughts?

functions.php

```
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
  'label' => 'Banner Image',
  'id' => 'secondary-image',
  'post_type' => array( 'research','events','people','labs','publications','projects','equipment','job','media','page' )
   ) );
}
```

template

```
<div class="banner banner-detail row" <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : ?> style="background-image: url('<?php MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url('media', 'secondary-image'); ?>');" <?php else : ?>style="background-image: url('/wp-content/themes/tqt/img/hero-dim.jpg')" <?php endif; ?> >
```

Comment: Hi, Jordan
Could you please add post type seperately? Please check below example :
`if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Secondary Image',
            'id' => 'secondary-image',
            'post_type' => 'post'
            'post_type' => 'page'
        )
    );
}`

Comment: @PunitPatel thanks for the reply! is post_type supposed to be set twice? 'post_type' => 'post' 'post_type' => 'page'

Comment: Yes, I have checked example of plugin and suggest you to update.

Comment: i have the most recent version of the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the thumbnail URL to use inside an inline style. You'll need `[the_post_thumbnail_url()][1]` to do so. `the_post_thumbnail()` returns the actual image, not the URL of the image (which you need to display it as a background image.

This particular plugin provides the `get_post_thumbnail_url()` function to do so.

You would use it like this (including the background-image property):

```
style="background-image: url('<?php MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); ?>');"
```

Also, note that if you're calling the `the_post_thumbnail()` function outside the loop you will need to provide a `$post_id`.

```
<?php
$attr = array(
    'id' => get_the_ID(),
);
MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail( get_post_type(), 'secondary-image', $attr );
?>
```

See [the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) in the WordPress codex, and the [multi post thumbnails](https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki) plugin Wiki and source code to see their implementation.

Comment: thanks can't believe i missed that! but now the url is empty

Comment: You might need to echo it: `<?php echo MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); ?>`. The function should return the url.

Comment: hmm... still no luck